# Entity Framework code-first approach one-to-one fluent api mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a one-to-one mapping with Entity Framework code-first (including fluent API mapping) approach. This is the first time I'm using code first approach.

When I run the `UpdateTaskCompleted()` method, it throws the following exception:

> Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

I suspect that I'm doing something wrong in fluent API mapping.

```
[Table("tblSession")]
public partial class tblSession
{
        [Key]
        public Guid SessionId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public tblTaskDetail tblTaskDetail { get; set; }
}

[Table("tblTaskDetail")]
public partial class tblTaskDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskDetailID { get; set; }

    public Guid? SessionID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string TaskStatus { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SessionID")]
    public tblSession tblSession { get; set; }
}

public class RequestSession
{
    [Key]
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; } 
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public TaskDetail TaskDetail { get; set; }
}

public class TaskDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskDetailID { get; set; }
    public Guid? SessionID { get; set; }
    public string TaskStatus { get; set; }
    public RequestSession RequestSession { get; set; }
}

public class TaskDetailMapper:EntityTypeConfiguration<TaskDetail>
{
    public TaskDetailMapper()
    {
        this.ToTable("tblTaskDetail");
        this.HasKey(hk => hk.TaskDetailID);
        HasRequired<RequestSession>(a => a.RequestSession)
                          .WithRequiredPrincipal(o => o.TaskDetail).Map(m => m.MapKey("SessionID"));

        this.Property(o => o.TaskStatus).HasColumnName("TaskStatus");
    }
}

public class RequestSessionMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<RequestSession>
{
    public RequestSessionMapper()
    {
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("tblSession");

        //Primary key
        this.HasKey<Guid>(hk => hk.SessionId);
        this.Property(t => t.SessionId).HasColumnName("SessionId");
        this.Property(t => t.IsActive).HasColumnName("IsActive");
    }
}

public partial class WarehouseAPIContext : DbContext
{
    public WarehouseAPIContext(): base("name=WarehouseAPIContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {           
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RequestSessionMapper());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TaskDetailMapper());
    }
}

public TaskDetail UpdateTaskCompleted(TaskDetail entity)
{
        try
        {
            var entry = dbSet.Find(entity.TaskDetailID);
            entry.TaskStatus = entity.TaskStatus;

            entity.RequestSession = new RequestSession()
            {
                IsActive = false
            };

            _context.SaveChanges(); 

            return entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TaskDetail.Id is of type int and Session.Id is of type Guid.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would choose to use either Annotation, or FluentAPI for configuring your model. There are edge-cases where features can only be done in one approach and not the other, but these are rare only a small handful and well documented.

I use FluentAPI as it is more expressive, and allows for all of the configuration to be in one place.

What you need to do here, is check out this very good resource on EF relationships: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx

A google for any entity framework issue/feature will have this site in its top results on the first page - Take some time and do a good bit of research before asking questions - Everyone is more than happy to help with answers, but by researching and reading material looking for the solution to your issues is where the real value will come from, as you will learn a lot more than just how to fix your current issue.